# Pure onclick scrollTo

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, scrollto

I am trying to invoke the `scrollTo` function directly from `onclick` action.
Found many solutions but none of them not worked form me

I am trying to do this:

```
<button onclick="$(window).scrollTo('#mydiv',100);"type="button"  placeholder="" />CLICK ME</button>

<div id="mydiv">
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
<button onclick="$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#mydiv').offset().top}, 2000);" type="button"  placeholder="" />CLICK ME</button>

<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Make sure you use jQuery 1.9.x

Comment: I must have tried at least 50 different methods tonight and this is the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

try with animate() something like: http://jsfiddle.net/C8p6f/

```
<button class="myButton" type="button"  placeholder="" />CLICK ME</button>
<div class="oneDiv">yyy</div>
<div id="mydiv">xxx</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.myButton').on('click',function(){
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#mydiv").offset().top}, 300);
        });
    });
</script>
```